# Error 403 while retrieving all the files in the Google Drive using domain-wide delegation

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apps, google-api-java-client, google-api-client

I am Getting Error 403 (You are not authorized to perform this request. That's all we know.) while retrieving all the files in the Google Drive using domain wide delegation. It is interesting as i am not getting the error for the first 12 times that i am acquiring the files but, after that i keep getting it.

Comment: are you able to get cause of ur error. If u can show me ur code in authentication. it will be much better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'r getting Error 403 than there can be various reason like -

```
403: The authenticated user has not installed the app with client id {clientId}
403: The authenticated user has not granted the app {appId} access to the file {fileId}
403: Invalid accessLevel. This method requires at least {requiredAcl} level access to act on the file with ID {fileId}
403: The app with id {appId} does not exist or is not properly configured as a Google Drive app
403: App with id {appId} cannot be used within the authenticated user's domain
403: The app with id {appId} is blacklisted as a Google Drive app
```

According to Google Drive Developer. Please Check [HERE](https://developers.google.com/drive/handle-errors?hl=en#403_the_authenticated_user_has_not_installed_the_app_with_client_id_clientid) for More Details. I hope you will be able to find out the cause of 403 Error.